# Sonata Admin Automatic Slug Validation

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-3.4

I have a form with a field named "title" and I'd prefer not to show the entity's "slug" property on the form at all, but I'd like to validate that the slug generated based on the title is unique.

I generate the slug during my admin's "preValidate()" function and the testing of uniqueness is happening thanks to the entity's annotation, which is nice, but:

Because there is no slug field on the form, the error just sits on the top (and doesn't even mention the field's name), which is quite useless.

So I'd either like to bind that error to my title field, or show a readonly slug field. I found that the latter seems easier, so I added the field with default empty string value, the problem is, that even after the form submit and the error message, the slug field remains an empty string, despite it having the value "asd-asd-asd" in the background.

I've dumped $this->getForm() during admin's preValidate() before and after setting the slug and I can see that in the "modelData, normData and viewData" all change.
In my knowledge, the form should display the field based on the viewData, so I don't understand.

I thought that maybe if I call the $form->handle($request), it would work, but it says it was already called.
I thought maybe I could do something with symfony's pre submit event, but then I found that I need admin's uniqid to access the form data of the request and I can't inject admin into the listener.
I also tried setting the slug in the controller's preCreate(), but it wasn't successful either.

How can I manipulate the form's field's values before it is filled based on the Request?
(Or why does it not show to the user?)